# How to run a shell script from another shell script reading first shell script name from a CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I have a parent script(parent.sh) written in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=","
cat testing.csv | while read line 
do
abcd="$line"
eval "$abcd";
done
```

And Child script(child.sh) written in bash, which i want to call from parent.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

date
```

In parent script, I am doing cat csv file(testing.csv) to read the name of child.sh, 
name of child file mentioned in csv file column like below:

```
./child.sh
```

Note: All the files child.sh, parent.sh and testing.csv are in same path

I am always getting an error "no such file or directory" and not able to execute child.sh from parent.sh when reading it's name from csv.

both child and parent script has chmod 777 permissions
I tried all the syntax to execute child inside parent, like:
sh child.sh , bash child.sh , source child.sh  but no success.

Please help me out!

Comment: "are in the same path"... so in _what_ path? Is that path contained in the process' `PATH` environment variable? Did you set it?

Comment: @arkascha  No, there is no PATH env. variable set, I meant it is in same folder

Comment: This works for me, unmodified. What is the exact error message you get? Is there any chance you have stray Windows line ends in the CSV file? I get the error ": No such file or directoryd.sh" if I force Windows line endings...

Comment: @Jon  , Yes this is the exact error I am getting "No such file or directoryd.sh"

Comment: @Jon,  From your point "stray windows line" , I got a clue, and found a sed -e 's/\r/\n/g'  on internet to get rid of this issue :)  , Your comment below dos2unix is not working because it is not installed, and I don't have permission to install it, But my issue is finally resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that you have Windows line endings in the CSV file. If you run

```
dos2unix testing.csv
```

the problem should go away.

Also, the use of `IFS` and `eval` is likely to upset people. Try something like

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read executable
do
        "$executable"
done <testing.csv
```